# Is there a way to make Mock() return different objects regarding to call arguments?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have this code to be tested (simplified):

```
def foo(job):
    stop1 = job.stops.get(stop_number=1)
    stop1.departed_at = first_scan['scan_date']
    stop2 = job.stops.get(stop_number=2)
    stop2.pod_time = pod['received_date']
```

So I do it like this:

```
    job = Mock()
    foo(job)
    self.assertIsInstance(job.sync_at, datetime.datetime)
    self.assertAlmostEqual(job.booked_at, isoformat('2019-10-01T00:00:00'))
    self.assertAlmostEqual(job.stops.get(stop_number=1).departed_at, isoformat('2019-10-07T05:24:47'))
    self.assertAlmostEqual(job.stops.get(stop_number=2).pod_time, isoformat('2019-10-07T12:00:00'))
```

The problem is that job.stops.get method return same object with any argument values:

```
>>> job.stops.get(stop_number=1)
<Mock name='mock.stops.get()' id='140194394261936'>
>>> job.stops.get(stop_number=2)
<Mock name='mock.stops.get()' id='140194394261936'>
>>>
```

So while testing the above code, I have both `job.stops.get(stop_number=1)` and `job.stops.get(stop_number=2)` returning the same output with both `departed_at` and `pod_time` attributes set. Because of this, I'm not sure that `pod_time` was set to stop2 not stop1 and vice versa.

Question is how to make `mock` return **different** instances regarding to `stop_number` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a callable to the [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) attribute of a `Mock` object. Make the callable return different objects based on different input arguments:

```
def mock_get(stop_number):
    return {
        1: Mock(departed_at='2019-10-07T05:24:47'),
        2: Mock(pod_time='2019-10-07T12:00:00')
    }[stop_number]

job = Mock()
job.stops.get.side_effect = mock_get
foo(job)
assert job.stops.get(stop_number=1).departed_at == '2019-10-07T05:24:47' # passes
assert job.stops.get(stop_number=2).pod_time == '2019-10-07T12:00:00' # passes
```

Comment: I can't get it. As I understand, mock_get will create a new Mock() instance each time when it's called. But I need to preserve these objects so departed_at and pod_time set in code that is being tested, not in mock_get function.

Comment: Ok, I got the idea of using side_effect, but still need to store these instances somewhere outside of function to have changes saved in this object